# Remover clase a elementos

Tags: javascript

Quiero quitar la clase `active` a los elementos en los que no se hicieron clic, estoy agregando la clase `active` cuando se da clic en cada elemento.

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab')
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider')

tabs.forEach((tab, i) => {
  tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let styles = `left: ${tab.offsetLeft}px;
       width: ${tab.offsetWidth}px;`;

    slider.style.cssText = styles
    tab.classList.add('active');
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tabs-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 55px;
  height: 35px
}

.tab {
  margin: 0px 20px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: .9em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab.active {
  color: red;
}

.slider {
  background-color: red;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 300ms left ease-in-out, 300ms width ease-in-out
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-container">
  <div class="tab active" data-tab="general">general</div>
  <div class="tab" data-tab="business">business</div>
  <div class="tab" data-tab="technology">technology</div>
  <div class="tab" data-tab="health">health</div>
  <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: @Bicho Lo mencione en la pregunta, quitar la clase active a los elementos en los que no se hicieron clic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te esta faltando es **quitar la clase `active` antes** de asignar esta al nuevo elemento *"clic-eado"*

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab')
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider')

tabs.forEach((tab, i) => {
  tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let styles = `left: ${tab.offsetLeft}px;
       width: ${tab.offsetWidth}px;`;
    slider.style.cssText = styles;
    
    // ACA Quitamos la class "active" primero
    tabs.forEach(t => t.classList.remove('active'));
    
    //
    tab.classList.add('active');
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tabs-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 55px;
  height: 35px
}

.tab {
  margin: 0px 20px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: .9em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab.active {
  color: red;
}

.slider {
  background-color: red;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 300ms left ease-in-out, 300ms width ease-in-out
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-container">
  <div class="tab active" data-tab="general">general</div>
  <div class="tab" data-tab="business">business</div>
  <div class="tab" data-tab="technology">technology</div>
  <div class="tab" data-tab="health">health</div>
  <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
```